# How to check if an exception is a FirebaseError / FirebaseAuthError in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement Firebase authentication and user creation on our server, working on TypeScript.

I'm creating a new user, and I have wrapped the whole creation inside a try-catch block. I'm trying to catch several exceptions, one of them being exception thrown by Firebase.

The problem is that I can't check if the exception was thrown by the Firebase, or if it's another type of exception.

Other answers to similar kind of questions suggest to check if the exception is an instance of FirebaseError:

```
let firebaseUser;
try {
    firebaseUser = await firebase.auth().createUser({
        email: email,
        password: password,
    });

    // Other code here
} catch (error) {
    if(error instanceof FirebaseError){
        // handle FirebaseError here
    }
}
```

The problem is, that when there is an error in the createUser function, the error is an instance of FirebaseAuthError, not FirebaseError, so this check fails.

I tried to switch it to FirebaseAuthError and import the FirebaseAuthError as well, but I get an error message:

> Package subpath './lib/utils/error' is not defined by "exports" in
> \node_modules\firebase-admin\package.json

So what would be the correct way to check that the caught exception is thrown by FirebaseAuth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best thing you can do, is writing a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to ensure your error is a FirebaseAuthError **that you will import using import type**. I checked, and it seems that it's because the library doesn't export it.

You can freely benefit from the type used by firebase, however, as the module is not listed in the exports, you won't be able to use it at runtime. the `import type` syntax allows you to still use it during development, but it will be completely ignored at build time.
That means you can't use `instanceof FirebaseAuthError` as only the type is imported, and you can't use `instanceof` on something else than a class.

I'm not sure about the following statement, but I guess that every error prefixed by `auth/` seem to be a FirebaseAuthError.

Thus, you could write a type guard as follows:

```ts
import type { FirebaseAuthError } from 'firebase-admin/lib/utils/error';


function isFirebaseAuthError(error: FirebaseError): error is FirebaseAuthError {
  return error.code.startsWith('auth/');
}
```

Comment: They are indeed interfaces, but there also exist classes for both. I can import FirebaseError from '@firebase/util', and use for checking the instanceof. FirebaseAuth also has a class implementation, but the problem is that it's not accessible for me to import.

But this solution seems workable, I think I can make a workaround with this sort of function. Thanks!

Comment: Just saw your edit, I think you're absolutely right. Firebase-auth library would need to be changed to export the FirebaseAuthError class, for me to be able to check if the exception is an instance of that class. That would be more elegant IMO, but this solution seems to work around it well.

Comment: Glad to hear ! I think the ultimate solution would be to open a PR on firebase to export it, you could eventually link it to this post
beware of this prefix thing though !